# Grab the part of the string using PHP

Tags: php

i have tried doing this using explode but not able to get what i want.
Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter.

```
$var = "ptitl=thiismytitile&bcolor=green&pwspecif=grabthis&auth=1&user=eshu.kotari@gmail.com&pass=secretepass";

$array = explode('&', $var);
```

which returns the string like "pwspecif=grabthis" but i only want "grabthis"

i would like to grab this part "grabthis" from above string.. anybody put some light on this.

Thank you

Regards,
Mona

Comment: You've already used `explode` to break the string into its parts; why can't you use it again on the substrings to split them into key and value pairs?

Comment: `$value = explode('=',$array[indexhere]); $value=$value[1]`

Comment: Hi Andrewsi.. thank you.. is there any way for to directly grab that...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your variable looks like a query string. You can simply use [`parse_str()`](http://php.net/parse_str) function to parse the string as if it were a query string passed via a URL.

```
parse_str($var);
echo $pwspecif;
```

If you want to make sure that it doesn't override any variables set in the current scope, you can make use of the second parameter (thanks to Glavic), like so:

```
parse_str($var, $arr);
echo $arr['pwspecif'];
```

Output:

```
grabthis
```

[**Demo!**](https://eval.in/52248)

Comment: Didn't know about this, very nice!

Comment: I advise you to use second parameter in `parse_str` function, so you don't set/override variables in current scope. This reminds me of register_globals, kinda evil ;)

Comment: @Glavić My question is why it doesn't return an array populated with the values by default. This sounds like a dangerous/irritating function if used improperly.

Comment: Great.. Amal.. thank you so much.. i was just trying to figure it out using explode... but your solution is great... Can i ask you one more thing.. can i replace directly "grabthis" with "editedgrab" thank you in advance...

Comment: @monamona: Directly replace? `str_replace('grabthis', 'editedgrab', $var);`

Comment: @ajp15243: if you click on link, that AmalMurali has posted, you will see that function returns `void`. If you like to populate array, see 2nd example in this answer.

Comment: thank you.. can i do this way str_replace($arr['pwspecif'], 'editedgrab', $var);

Comment: @Glavić I know it returns `void`, and I know you can use the second parameter. I'm arguing that the function itself is designed poorly because *by default* it loads variables into the current scope, and you have to *opt in* to putting them into an array (essentially their own private scope). That is a terrible design, particularly for PHP novices. I'm saying it would probably be better to simply return a populated array by default.

Comment: str_replace($arr['pwspecif'], 'editedgrabrag', $var) will work... but it will replace all occurrence.. i just want to replace...$arr['pwspecif'] position...string.. any idea please..

Comment: @ajp15243: I agree, function should return array. If some1 wanted to extract array variables to local scope, they can do that with [extract()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function, so really there is no good reason why `parse_str` works as it does ;-(

Comment: @monamona: Use `http_build_query`, then. `echo http_build_query($arr);` should give what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You need to explode the string again on `=`, just like you did with `&`

```
$value = explode('=',$array[indexhere]); 
$value=$value[1]
```

Where `indexhere` is the index at which `pwspecif=grabthis` is in `$array`

Answer (score 1):

```
$var = "ptitl=thiismytitile&bcolor=green&pwspecif=grabthis&auth=1&user=eshu.kotari@gmail.com&pass=secretepass";
    $chars = preg_split('/&/', $var, -1, PREG_SPLIT_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    $chars1=$chars[2][0];
    $arr3=explode('=', $chars1);
    echo $arr3[0];
```

If you are sure that "pwspecif" is 3rd parameter always then use the above code.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that "pwspecif" is 3rd parameter always then use the below code.

```
$var = "ptitl=thiismytitile&bcolor=green&pwspecif=grabthis&auth=1&user=eshu.kotari@gmail.com&pass=secretepass";

$array = explode('=', $var);
$arr2=$array[3];
$arr3=explode('&', $arr2);
echo $arr3[0];
```